# Temperature conversion code in Java won't run?

Tags: java, debugging, runtime-error

Ok,so I'm a complete novice at programming and I just started coding in Java. I tried to write a code for temperature conversion (Celsius to Fahrenheit) and for some reason it simply won't run! Please, help me find out errors in this code(however silly it may be).

Here's the code:

```
  package tempConvert;

  import java.util.Scanner;

  public class StartCode {

      Scanner in = new Scanner(System. in );

      public double tempInFarenheit;

      public double tempInCelcius;

      {
          System.out.println("enter the temp in celcius");

          tempInCelcius = in .nextDouble();

          tempInFarenheit = (9 / 5) * (tempInCelcius + 32);

          System.out.println(tempInFarenheit);
      }
  }
```

Comment: 1) *"for some reason it simply won't run!"*  'Some reason' is usually quite explicitly stated by the compiler or JRE.  In future, please copy/paste the text of those messages. 2) Is this [tag:homework]?
 3) Please use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks. 4) You are apparently yet to get to the problem with `9/5` ;)

Comment: 5) `(9/5)*(tempInCelcius+32)` I am also pretty sure that bracketing is wrong..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to write the main method which is the start point for a program to run. Let me modify your code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StartCode 
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in); 
    public double tempInFarenheit;
    public double  tempInCelcius;
```

**public static void main (String[] args)**

```
    {
        System.out.println("enter the temp in celcius");

        tempInCelcius = in.nextDouble() ;    
        tempInFarenheit = (9/5)*(tempInCelcius+32);

        System.out.println(tempInFarenheit);
    } 
}
```

Comment: if this is good please mark it as your answer :) good luck with your coding!

Comment: That wasn't his problem...yet :P

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help but "tempInCelcius" and "tempInFarenheit" are non static fields. aren't they ?? In this case this method would be invalid (correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: You cannot reference non-static fields from a static method.

Comment: *"In this case this method would be invalid (correct me if I'm wrong)"*  The compiler is the 'acid test'.

Comment: this method is standard. I wrote it as static since it is a 'class method'. By static I mean, you don't have to instantiate an object of this class new StartCode() to call Main, but in case you call it from somewhere else (which should not be the case here), you would write StartCode.Main(); Anyhow, the non static variables should not be a problem in this case. If so, try and move them in the main method.

Comment: *"if this is good"* It's not especially good, no.  As help for homework(1) it is both too explicit and wrong.  Otherwise it is ..just wrong, and misses several important points. 1) Undetermined at this stage, but who codes a temperature converter for fun?

Comment: In the code you posted above you add 32 to the Celsius temperature and _then_ multiply it with 9/5 (remember PEMDAS?). You want to call `(tempInCelsius*(9/5))+32` instead so the +32 happens after the multiplication. Good luck!

Comment: *"what's my logical error ?"*  In case you are confused.  This is not a help desk.  What I mean by that is that I asked you an explicit question some 15+ minutes before you made that comment.  I expect an answer to my question.  Are you ignoring me?

Comment: @Andrew No! I wasn't ignoring you I think I hadn't seen your question.I'm still trying to figure out how this forum works.This is NOT a homework question(that's why I didn't tag it) and YES I was doing this for fun and I NEVER asked whether this was good ! That comment wasn't mine !!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is going to work better for you:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StartCode
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
        double tempInFarenheit;
        double  tempInCelcius;
        System.out.println("enter the temp in celcius");
        tempInCelcius = in.nextDouble() ;
        tempInFarenheit = 1.8*tempInCelcius+32;
        System.out.println(tempInFarenheit);
    }
}
```

You equation for Farenheit was incorrect.  Integer division isn't for you, either.

Answer (score 0):

You need a [main method](http://www.geom.uiuc.edu/~daeron/docs/javaguide/java/nutsandbolts/main.html). I also suggest using an IDE such as Eclipse, which can generate the skeleton code for you (including the syntax of the main method).

Comment: A person who can't write a main method should not start with Eclipse.  They'll be ignorant of two things then.

Comment: That's one perspective and I agree with you partially. However, it can be discouraging not to get past syntax errors using notepad and javac. I'm sure this debate has been fought before on the interwebs.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
public class DegreeToFahrenheit {


    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);  

        System.out.println("Enter a temperature: ");  
        double temperature = input.nextDouble();  
        System.out.println("Enter the letter of the temperature type. Ex: C or c for celsius, F or f for fahrenheit.: ");  

        String tempType = input.next();  


        String C = tempType;  
        String c = tempType;  

        String F = tempType;  
        String f = tempType;  

        double celsius = temperature;  
        double fahrenheit = temperature;  

        if(tempType.equals(C) || tempType.equals(c)) { 
            celsius = (5*(fahrenheit-32)/9);  
            System.out.print("The fahrenheit degree " + fahrenheit + " is " + celsius + " in celsius." );


        }  


        else if(tempType.equals(F) || tempType.equals(f)) {  

            fahrenheit = (9*(celsius/5)+32);  
            System.out.print("The celsius degree " + celsius + " is " + fahrenheit + " in fahrenheit." ); 
        }  

        else {  
            System.out.print("The temperature type is not recognized." );  
        }  
    }  

}
```